# Android, put a logo on the corner of the live call using apps like skype?

Tags: android, skype, live-streaming

Basically, what I want to do is add some picture (and in a more advanced form, a video) to the video stream by an app like Skype on Android when one video calls someone else.

One idea can be intercepting network packets on (maybe) native layout of Android architecture so we can add our desired graphics and dispatch them out.
Another idea is override the android camera API (or any other part that involves providing picture frames to live streaming processes) in a way that we can add our desired graphic elements.

However the above two are not the ultimate ways to establish the goal. 
Any idea about details on intercepting network packages or overriding camera will be appreciated. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's just a transparent overlay, not part of the actual camera image

Comment: Do you mean adding a video call element inside a video call element??

Comment: Not two video calls, just a video call and another is like a patch on the video, a strip at the bottom of the video showing a picture and the like @AnasAijaz

Comment: Its easier to implement than the first one just put an image view insead of surface view and change it with java when you want to use it

Answer (score 0):

**Do you mean this?**

[image]

This can be achieved by placing a Surface View and making it's size match parent then another above it **Use Relative Layout**.